# Maintain Model when doing Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor syntax html page that shows some data of a model that is passed from the controller to the view. After the data is presented, the user can click on a button related to some item in my model, so more item-related-data will be presented based on the button clicked.

To achieve this, i am trying to post to the controller the id (integer), so the controller will write to ViewData and reload the page with the **same** model, but now the page will show more information from the model (because the user clicked on the button..). But i just cant figure out how to maintain the same complex model object.

My Controller:

```
    // The Entry point to the controller
    [Route("[controller]/[action]/cardNumber")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Inspect(string cardNumber)
    {
        var dataObject = GetDataObjectModel();

        return View(dataObject);
    }

    [Route("[controller]/[action]/model/ruleId")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ExpandRules(int ruleId)
    {
        ViewData["RuleId"] = ruleId;
        return View("Inspect"); // Somehow need to use same model from above here
    }
```

Inspect.cshtml:

```
<table>
            <caption>Rules</caption>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Expand DoorGroups</th>
                <th>Rule Name</th>
                <th>Exists in Database</th>
                <th>Exists in Staging Card</th>
                <th>Exists in Proxy</th>
                <th>Exists in Controller</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            @if (Model.RulesFromDb != null)
            {
                foreach (var rule in Model.RulesFromDb)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
              <!-- THE BUTTON -->
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("ExpandRules", "Inspector", new {ruleId = rule.Id}, FormMethod.Post))
                            {
                                <input type="submit" value="+"/>
                            } 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => rule.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            V
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @(Model.RulesFromStaging.Exists(x => x.Id == rule.Id) ? "V" : "X")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (Model.RulesFromProxy != null)
                            {
                                @(Model.RulesFromProxy.Exists(x => x.Id == rule.Id) ? "V" : "X")
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.Raw("Data not Provided")
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (Model.RulesFromController != null)
                            {
                                @(Model.RulesFromController.Exists(x => x.Id == rule.Id) ? "V" : "X")
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.Raw("Data not Provided")
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Is `cardNumber` what determines the model you initially display? If so, you should post that value back as well in order to rebuild the model (and do you have the `[HttpPost]` on the wrong method?)

Comment: But you would get far better performance by using ajax and just returning a partial view of what you want and add that to the current view

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes the cardNumber is what determines the initial display, but i generate that model from a complex logic using databse queries as well so i really dont want to re-build this model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke even with the partial view im still left with the same problem (as far as i can tell)

Comment: Then using ajax to load a partial view of just the data you want (based on `ruleId`) would be the best solution (but you have not shown you models of what data you are loading or where/how its displayed so a bit hard to help any further)

Comment: If i use ajax to load a partial view do i get to keep my model? how?

The model itself is a basically a bunch of lists, each list has a few of its own lists, and those lists also have some lists.. every list has also some integers/strings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180868/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tomer-something).